# What happens when using PDO->beginTransaction when the database does not support transactions?

Tags: php, database, pdo, transactions

I read [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php) on the official documentation that not all drivers support transactions, therefore PDO runs in auto-commit mode, but I read [here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) that running `PDO->beginTransaction()` shuts off auto-commit. So what if a driver doesn't support transactions? Will a PDOException be thrown and that's just the end of it? If some drivers don't support transactions, does that mean some users will not be able to use my application successfully, or am I confusing server drivers with client OS drivers? I am a bit boggled here. Any explanation would be quite helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the driver does not support transactions, it will throw an exception. Therefore, your application will not be used successfully. On other hand, if the table itself does not support transaction, but the driver does, it will continue with the code.

For me it's pretty normal, even using an universal library like PDO, to not be able to run your application on every platform. You need to make cases for drivers. Like cases for differet browsers.

Comment: So when it says "not every driver supports transactions" does that mean the server (the one that is delivering the web page) to the user or does that mean the user's drivers don't support transactions, which would mean I would need to use cases like you say so that everyone can use my application?

Comment: It depends on how your application runs. I.e. if it's like a facebook API, where the database is stored on the server on your costumers and you have connection to this database via a connector method with params $user, $pass, $host, $driver, $db, and your costumer sends $driver as a non-transaction supporting db, you are checking if this param is either a supporting or not, db, and if it's -> begin with transactions, if not -> another logic